# Crystal Report Sub Report paging/positioning

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a report that has 2 sub-reports,

First Subreport - top to middle main report, 12 rows max, and rows after 12 will be on next page. I used the "Next Page After" with Formula: (Remainder(GroupNumber, 12) = 0 And Not ONLASTRECORD).

The Second Subreport will have same requirement, 12 rows max and rows after 12 will be no next page.

My problem I cannot make the second Subreport display at middle of page on 2nd page.

If I put the 2 Subreports in same section the the data of both subreports is displayed at top of page (overlapping).

If I put the 2 subreports in different Sections (Report Footer a and b). The Second Subreport is starting after last page the First SubReport.

Report Design:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1DsW.jpg)

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the 2nd subreport object,

select the menu option of '***Format Subreport...***' and,

under the '***Common***' tab, turn of the option of '***Keep Object Together***'.